# How can I get this NodeJS asynchronous loop to execute properly?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have tried a thousand ways to do this, but none work properly. Here msg1 and msg2 are stand ins for functions that I want to call synchronously (first one then the other). A for loop produces "unknown" in the second loop.  After searching, I think this is the right way to do it, but I am still not there. The answer that I would like to get is:

```
msg1
msg2
```

but I am getting

```
msg1
msg1
```

Here is my code

```
var data = {
  "messages": ["msg1", "msg2"],
  "i": -1
}

const increment = async () => {
  data.i = await data.i + 1;
};

const test = async () => {
  data.messages.forEach((fcn) => {
    increment(data)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(data.messages[data.i])
      return data
    })
  })
};

test(data)
```

UPDATE

the asynchronous answer from jfriend00 (below) works!!!  BUT, when used in my actual code, it runs one extra time producing "undefined" in the final loop. I have tried changing the starting value for i, different formulations of the for loop and adding a check for the value "undefined" (as below), but the undefined value remains goes undetected. I have also lengthened the delay (unsuccessful). How can I ensure that the loop only runs once per message?

```
if (data.i !== undefined) {
 console.log(data.messages[data.i])     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's nothing asynchronous here, you can just remove all the `async`, `await` and `.then()` and then run your synchronous code (you can run each of these snippets directly, right in the browser to see what they send to the console).

```js
var data = {
    "messages": ["msg1", "msg2"],
    "i": -1
}

const increment = () => {
    ++data.i;
};

const test = () => {
    data.messages.forEach((fcn) => {
        increment(data)
        console.log(data.messages[data.i])
    });
};

test(data)
```

---

If you want the `increment()` function to be an actual asynchronous operation and you want to sequence the calls to `increment()` then, you have to ditch `.forEach()` and use a `for` loop and use `await` appropriately and insert something that is actually asynchronous into the `increment()` function (I inserted a promise-based delay):

```js
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

var data = {
    "messages": ["msg1", "msg2"],
    "i": -1
}

const increment = async () => {
    await delay(100);
    ++data.i;
};

const test = async () => {
    for (let msg of data.messages) {
        await increment(data);
        console.log(data.messages[data.i])
    }
};

test(data)
```

**Comments**

Your existing code is misusing `async`, `await` and `.then()`.  There are no asynchronous operations anywhere in your existing code so there's no reason for any of `async`, `await` and `.then()` as that just makes things more complicated than required.

In addition, you only ever use `await` when you are awaiting a promise.  So, `data.i = await data.i + 1;` is misguided.  It will run, but the `await` doesn't do anything useful - it only makes the code more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain what the delay does?  Is it functional?  When I put functions in place of the messages in the code, it runs though the two functions as expected, but then tries to execute a third "unknown" function. I have tried to increase the timeout without success. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Oddly, testing the unknown value does not help. I have added more in the original question.

Comment: @user3877654 - I have no idea at all what either of those last two comments means.  I can't comment on code  you're trying that I can't see.  The `delay()` function returns a promise that resolves in a period of time.  It is used as a substitute for an asynchronous operation that returns a promise and resolves some time in the future.  Hacking on timeouts to try to make something work is never the right approach.

Comment: I found the error - it was in the function being called, however, the error never points to that function.  thank you for your help!